# Does Stack Overflow provide a public API for querying?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, api

I'm interested in possibly writing an aggregation application for subject/tags interested in.

Will Stack Overload be providing some sort of API for the public?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api

Answer (score 16):

See [StackApps](http://stackapps.com).

And, for completeness, [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) for online querying of our data.

Answer (score 7):

The current version of the Stack Exchange API, (which covers Stack Overflow) can be found at https://api.stackexchange.com/.

- [Blog Post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/)
- [Documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)
- [App registration link](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) (required for unrestricted usage)

Answer (score 3):

You can download the [Stack Overflow Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) under a Creative Commons license, and query the entire thing yourself.

As mentioned in the article, it's anonymised, and by its nature it won't be up to date, but it'll certainly give you the ability to run your own stats :)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for tags: You can subscribe to the RSS feed for particular tags. Here's the one for the "python" tag, for example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python

Just click on the tag you're interested in, and then on the RSS symbol [alt text http://sstatic.net/so/Img/feed-icon-small.png](http://sstatic.net/so/Img/feed-icon-small.png).