# Status of the Stackoverflow API

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, api

As per the answers in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stackoverflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying), public API was a priority for Jeff, back in August.

I'd like to know when it will be available.

Thanks!

Comment: It will take some 6 to 8 weeks to wrap it up...

Answer (score 7):

Sometime this year. Ideally sooner rather than later. It is a high priority, but I have a lot on my [mind grapes](http://mindgrapes.net/).

Update: now in **private** beta, and will remain so for 30-60 days so we make sure we get it right for V1. We don't want to go public until we feel confident it's right. Email team@stackoverflow.com with your intended use case if you want to contribute.

Comment: I'd love to test anyone else's API, so go Jon make me something sweet!

Comment: I'd love to test the API too.

Answer (score 1):

I applaud the team for taking a whole 9 months to get it right, rather than rushing something out in 6-8 weeks.  Once you release a "supported" api, it's *very* hard to change it — much more so even than interface features or reputation scoring on the main site.

This is assuming, of course, that they did get it right.  That's even harder than making changes after release.

Answer (score 0):

See http://StackApps.com .