# Does stackoverflow have an API?

Tags: discussion, api, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does StackOverflow provide a public API for querying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stackoverflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying)

Does stackoverflow have a public API? Can you access the stack overflow data, questions and answers through an API. If so what libraries are there to interface with this API?

Comment: Meta question!!

Comment: Or leave here and point people to meta I had no idea what meta was when I first started using stack

Comment: Well, that's cute, but you could say that about any question that belongs on Meta. Let's have a copy of every meta question here, for the people who don't know what Meta is, right? Somehow I doubt it will work...

Comment: Point taken....

Answer (score 3):

[Gee, I wonder...](http://api.stackexchange.com/) (P.S. ever scroll down to the bottom of the page?)[image]

Comment: I asked it as a pointer to others. It's a meta question!

Comment: @MattAlcock - First of all, meta questions go to the meta website. Secondly, all the links are right there, at the bottom of every page. Anybody who is truly interested can find them in less than 30 seconds. I'm sorry, but this question is pretty much offtopic. :(

Comment: In the interst of search I would keep it but if it gets voted to close then i agree

Comment: To be honest, search [already has](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackoverflow+api) plenty of questions about the API itself; a lot of them also include links to the API docs and stuff. I don't see how this question improves anything.

Comment: Requested deletetion

Comment: @MattAlcock - Wow. Now I feel like a bully. :P Well... don't take it so hard. I've made some similarly stupid questions myself here. :)