# Stack Overflow API for Java

Tags: discussion, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Stack Overflow provide a public API for querying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stackoverflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying)

Do we have Stack Overflow API for Java? If yes, where can I get it?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stackoverflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://soapi.info/. It's REST so any REST client library for Java will do the job.

Comment: thanks Darin for your quick reply. I don't have any idea about REST, can you explain a bit then it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: @Mahendra Athneria, you may checkout [this project](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/).

Answer (score 5):

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is the place to look for information regarding the Stack Overflow API. There have been three wrappers written in Java:

- [StackWrap4J Java wrapper](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) (disclosure: I co-authored this one)
- [StackExchange Java client library](https://stackapps.com/questions/258/stackexchange-java-client-library)
- [stackoverflow-java-sdk: Java wrapper for StackExchange API](https://stackapps.com/questions/236/stackoverflow-java-sdk-java-wrapper-for-stackexchange-api)